# Show a message when checking a checkbox and show another message when unchecking it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm fairly new in Javascript/AngularJS and want to play around with it to learn/understand these languages. On the Angular website there's a little basic to do list script I want to change a little. I've changed it into a checklist of things I need to learn. When i check the checkbox I got a little msg like, 'well done!'. But when I uncheck it, the same msg pops up and that I want to change in something like, 'you sure?'.

I've spent several hours on looking for the answer but couldn't find the answer so I hope someone can help me figuring out how to do this. This is my code:

HTML:

```
      <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
        <span>Nog {{todoList.remaining()}} van de {{todoList.todos.length}} te gaan!</span>
        <!--[ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]-->
        <ul class="unstyled">
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('Well done!')" ng-model="todo.done">
              <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!--einde ng-controller -->
```

AngularJS code:

```
todoList.remaining = function() {
  var count = 0;
  angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo) {
    count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
  });
  return count;
};

todoList.archive = function() {
  var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
  todoList.todos = [];
  angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
    if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
  });
};
```

If there's missing something, let me know! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code for you:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
        <span>Nog {{todoList.remaining()}} van de {{todoList.todos.length}} te gaan!</span>
        <!--[ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]-->
        <ul class="unstyled">
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" onclick="showAlert(todo.done)" ng-model="todo.done">
              <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!--einde ng-controller -->
```

AngularJs Code:

```
todoList.remaining = function() {
  var count = 0;
  angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo) {
    count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
  });
  return count;
};

  $scope.showAlert = function(isSuccess){
               if(isSuccess)
                  alert('Well done!')
               else
                 alert('Unchecked')
                };
todoList.archive = function() {
  var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
  todoList.todos = [];
  angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
    if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! A simple copy paste won't do it for me and I've looked into it for a bit and could't really figure out what's wrong with it. I see what you did with the $scope and understand the logic of it, but it seems to erase this list it was showing before:

    angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', function() {
    var todoList = this;
    todoList.todos = [
      {text:'Leer HTML5', done:true},
      {text:'Leer CSS3', done:true},
      {text:'Leer Javascript', done:false},
      ];

Comment: Or is it maybe possible that you only be able to check the checkbox and can't uncheck it?